# Conditional section numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering, unnumbered-sections

I would like to find or implement a system in which LaTeX would compile a numbered (sub)section only if they are followed by another (sub)section. Otherwise the (sub)section would remain unnumbered. In practice it would mean:

```
 i. Section               (numbered)
    ii. Subsection        (numbered)
    ii. Subsection        (numbered)
i. Section                (numbered)
    * Subsection          (unnumbered)
i. Section                (numbered)
    ii. Subsection        (numbered)
    ii. Subsection        (numbered)
        * Subsubsection   (unnumbered)
    ii. Subsection        (numbered)
```

So I need for LaTeX to number a (sub)section only if the counter of (sub)sections ever reaches a value greater than 1 inside the current section level. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

This obviously needs a two-pass system.

In the `.aux` file I store the necessary information and at the next run a check on whether more than one sectional units are present at the given level.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy{\latexsubsection}{\subsection}
\NewCommandCopy{\latexsubsubsection}{\subsubsection}

% a generic infrastructure
\NewDocumentCommand{\genericlevel}{mmsO{#5}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#3}{%
    #1*{#5}% call is \level*
  }{%
    \wantsnumberingTF{#2}{%
      #1[#4]{#5}%
    }{%
      #1*{#5}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#2}{#4}%
      \stepcounter{#2}%
    }
  }
}
% redefine the levels to use the generic infrastructure
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{}{\genericlevel{\latexsubsection}{subsection}}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsubsection}{}{\genericlevel{\latexsubsubsection}{subsubsection}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\wantsnumberingTF}{mmm}
 {
  % first write the relevant info
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
   {
    \str_case:nn { #1 }
     {
      {subsection}{\arabic{section}}
      {subsubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
     }
   }
  \iow_now:cx {@auxout}
   {
    \savednumber { \l_tmpa_tl } { \arabic{#1} }
   }
  % now check whether the relevant number is greater than zero
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { savednumber\l_tmpa_tl }
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { \use:c { savednumber\l_tmpa_tl } > 0 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    #2
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\savednumber}{mm}
 {
  \cs_gset:cpn { savednumber#1 } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Numbered}
\subsection{Numbered}
\subsection{Numbered}
\section{Numbered}
\subsection{Unnumbered}
\section{Numbered}
\subsection{Numbered}
\subsubsection{Numbered}
\subsubsection{Numbered}
\subsection{Numbered}
\subsubsection{Unnumbered}
\subsection{Numbered}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and for providing a working example!